# when i subtract 8 hours from a date it should change the date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i want to consider only 8 hours in a day. means when i add 8 hours to one day it should change the date automatically.

Example :

```
2015-05-24 00:00:00.000 + 8 hours = 2015-05-25 00:00:00:00
```

Is it possible to it in sql

Comment: You can use case when condition

Comment: Your code will have to look at the number of hours and modify the date properly.  E.g., `datecol = datecol + (@hours * 3)`.  The `* 3` converts the 8-hour day to a normal 24-hour one that sql databases are usually for.

Comment: i am just a beginner. i would really appreciate if you could explain it a bit

Comment: Is this for a single select or would you like it to be for all the dates in your database? Also, is it MySql, Sql Server, Oracle, ms access, postgre, db2?

Comment: i am storing it in a variable. and it is in sql server 2008

Comment: What is 2015-05-24 00:00:00 + 7:59? is it 2015-05-24 07:59:00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
SELECT @StartTm=CASE WHEN @SOSlckTm=8 THEN
DATEADD(day,1,@SODocDueD)
end
```

Comment: i dont have any hour column. the date is shored in datetime variable.

Comment: How are you checking ?

Comment: it is something like this
SELECT @StartTm = DATEADD(hours,@SOSlckTm,@SODocDueDt) 
both starttm and sodocduedt are datetime variables. when i add soslcktm if it is 8 or greater than 8 then it should change the date to next date

Comment: RDBMS name ? SQL Server or Oracle ?